# How can I successfully exchange my Indian or Digital Rupee Currency into my BTC wallet?

Tags: buy-bitcoins

I need information how to transfer from my Rupee eWallet and set amount of earned Currency, then send it to my Bitcoin Wallet. Any advice would be appreciated.